# SQL Server 2008. sort and insert custom rows in result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have table for comunication between clients and operaters, which contains phone, id (1=client, 2=operater) date, message... and some other data.

I need to make stored procedure which will sort table like this

```
number1 operaters message
number1 clients message
number1 clients message
number1 operaters message
number1 *no message*
.
.
.
```

So, bassically, I need to find first message sent by operater and then client messages before next operaters message.
If after one operaters message there is no clients answer, I need to insert row like "no clients anwer" or something like that.

And that is large table, so will be good if it is less steps.

I know how to order by multiple columns, I know how to find first operaters message (select min time where id...) but I don't know how to insert those rows where needed.

Thanks in advance for help.

And yeah, it's MSSQL.

Comment: Do these entries have time stamps?

Comment: Yes, there is timestamp.

Comment: How do you match the operator message to client message? Are they always supposed to be consecutive (relative to timestamp ordering) or do you have a self-referencing FOREIGN KEY that does that? Your example also suggests there may be more than one client message for each operator message - is that correct?

Comment: Both client and operater messages have client's number in specific column.

Comment: Yes, it can be more than one messages after operater's message, just first should be chosen first operater's message, and then client's message(s) after that, but before next operater's message. And then next operater's message, and client's messages after that, and so on, for every number.

Comment: How do you distinguish between operator and client messages? Is this purely a function of ordering - i.e. first message under given NUMBER is always considered operator and all the rest are automatically considered client? Or there is some other criteria (e.g. some field you have not shown us)?

Comment: I have UserID, where 1=client, 2=operater.

Comment: I have column which explains whether it is customer or operater. Id there is ID 1, then its client, if 2, then customer).

This is not necessarily function of ordering, any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't actually test it, but this general idea should work:

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE(NUMBER, DATE, USER_ID, MESSAGE)
SELECT NUMBER, GETDATE(), 1, '*no message*'
FROM YOUR_TABLE T1
WHERE
    USER_ID = 2                       -- Operator.
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM YOUR_TABLE T2
        WHERE
            T1.NUMBER = T2.NUMBER
            AND T1.DATE <= T2.DATE
            AND USER_ID = 1           -- Client.
    )
```

In plain English: for each operator message that does not have a younger client message, insert a new client message.

*(Based on your comment, `USER_ID = 1` signifies a client and `USER_ID = 2` operator.)*

Also note that using `GETDATE()`assumes all other dates are correct (i.e. none of them are in the future), implying that newly inserted message must be younger than its "parent" operator message. If that cannot be assumed, you'll probably need to use `DATEADD` on operator message's DATE.